# Document greyed out in document browser

Tags: swift, uidocument, uti

I tried to build an app based on the `Document based app` template. I am trying to get it to open markdown files. I got it to create the files and show up in the share sheet when viewing the file in the Files app. However in the Document Browser in the app (`UIDocumentBrowserViewController`) it is greyed out and cannot be selected. I can't really find what this is due. How do I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it a second time, still did not work. A few days later however, the second one started working, the first one is still broken.